# Windows Gadget Style Behavior in Different Programming Languages

Tags: c#, java, visual-studio, desktop, windows-desktop-gadgets

I really don't know where to begin in approaching this problem, so I apologize in advance if this is a broad question.

I want to develop an application in a programming language (Maybe C#, Java, Visual Basic), and have it behave like a Windows Gadget; I want it to behave as if it is embedded in the Windows desktop. Gadgets seem to be phased out in Windows 8, so I don't know if that approach would be best. I want to develop a "news feed" style application, and would like it to behave just like it was actually a part of the desktop.

Is it possible to accomplish this by using a programming language of my choosing and emulating Gadget behavior? Or am I restricted to just creating gadgets using the Gadget API?

Or am I just thinking too much ;P Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you could easily do this in say C#.NET. I.e. create a borderless form with no minimize/close buttons, which would remain in the background when other applications are on top.

Comment: Wow, as I was typing the same exact answer to my own question! You win; I don't know why this didn't come to me at the time... pretty simple really.